# How does the Covariance Formula make sense logically and intuitionally?

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, mathematical-modeling, covariance

The covariance formula gives the linear relatinship between two variables and is an extension of Variance formula , given by E((X-X')(Y-Y')). Can somebody explain how the formula is able to capture the relationship between the two variables both in a logically and in an intuitional sense of how the math works, as i am finding it difficult to conceptualize it.

Comment: Presumably you mean $E[(X-E[X])(Y- E[Y])]$.  Can you see why it is $0$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, is $Var(X)$ when $X=Y$ and is $-Var(X)$ when $X=-Y$?